# Session is put into MYSQL database, but not displaying after change

Tags: php, ajax

I'm wondering how to set the `$_SESSION['example']` after: `$example = $_POST['example'];`
I'm using AJAX, and the codes I have now (see below) Works, meaning example does get saved into the MYSQL database, but even when I refresh the page, `echo $SESSION['example']` doesn't change. Which is what I would like. Any help is much appreciated here are my relevant codes:

```
$.ajax({
url: "phpfiles/page.php",type: "POST",data: {action: 'save',
example: Level },
success: function() {console.log("msg");}});}
```

heres 'page.php'

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$example = $_POST['example'];
mysql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME SET example='$example' WHERE user_ip='$user_ip'", $link); 
mysql_close($link);
    }
?>
```

My session code works, but NOT after the example changes, But it DOES save in the MYSQL  database. Here is the code I'm using to display the table item:

```
echo $_SESSION['example'];
```

**EDIT:** I do have session_start(); at the start of any file I'm using session in.
I am just trying to get echo $_SESSION['example']; to work After the AJAX call, right now it only displays Before the ajax call. However, it Is saving to the MYSQL database after the Update ajax call. I have also tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['example'];
```

But that brings up a POST page.php error.

Comment: Which page you are unable to get this value in `page.php` or ajax call script?

Comment: I'm unable to get this value AFTER the UPDATE in the echo $_SESSION['example'], which is on a whole different page. But it displays fine before its updated, and even stores in the MYSQL database. Basically all I am asking is how to:
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['example'];

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear from your question where you want to get this value.
If you are trying to get in page.php then here is the code.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
         $stage = $_POST['example'];
         $_SESSION['example'] = $stage;
         mysql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME SET example='$example' WHERE user_ip='$user_ip'", $link); 
         mysql_close($link);
    }

    echo $_SESSION['example'];
  ?>
```

If you are trying this value in ajax call script then insure that you have 
start session (e.g `session_start();` )in that script.

**Edit** :- If you are using session then please make sure session_start() in that script before using session value.

Comment: I do have session_start(); at the top of any page im using session in, I tried your script but the result is the same. It's saving the MYSQL database but not displaying anything different.